# emacs-jedi does not find numpy completions

Tags: python, emacs, numpy, python-jedi

I installed emacs-jedi to get some code completion for python in emacs. In general, I must say that I am very impressed! It works well out of the box and finds completions quickly for built -in libraries. However, I use python for scientific purposes and rely on numpy and scipy for my work. For some reason, I get no completions for these modules.

Example:

```
import numpy 

testVector = numpy.array([1,2,3])
```

now typing testVector. and waiting, nothing shows up

Answer (score 6):

I wonder why it does not work.  It looks like `sys.path` problem but it should work without any configuration.  But here is some idea for a brute force fix.

(1) Run the following script to get load path for numpy.

```
import os
import numpy
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(numpy.__file__)))
```

(2) Set `jedi:server-args` like this to forcefully add the path.

```
(setq jedi:server-args
      '("--sys-path" "THE/PRINTED/PATH/FOR/NUMPY"
        "--sys-path" "THE/PRINTED/PATH/FOR/SCIPY"))
```

See also: http://tkf.github.com/emacs-jedi/#jedi:server-args

---

**Edit 1**

Reading your comment on @syohex's answer, it looks like you mixed up some installation methods.  jeid.el uses the virtualenv "env/" in the directory in which you have jedi.el, if it exists.  el-get automatically creates "env/" if you have virtualenv.  So, if you like system installation, you need to tell Jedi.el to ignore "evn/" by doing this:

```
(require 'jedi)
(setq jedi:server-command (list "python" jedi:server-script))
```

See also: http://tkf.github.com/emacs-jedi/#jedi:server-command

---

**Edit 2**

I have no clue why is that happening from your description.  Here are several ways to narrow down the problem.

1. Run `make tryout` in the directory in which jedi.el is installed (like `~/.emacs.d/el-get/jedi/`).

   This opens a clean (i.e., it does not read your setup) Emacs process with minimal setup for jedi.el.  Let's see if you can complete numpy and scipy.
2. Can you import numpy and scipy *in Emacs*?  You could have different environment variable in Emacs and shell.  Run `M-! python -c 'import numpy' RET`.  If this does not give you an error, then it is fine.
3. Can you import numpy and scipy using `env/bin/python`?  The best way to do it is to check it from Emacs.

   So first go to the directory in which jedi.el is installed (e.g., `C-x C-f ~/.emacs.d/el-get/jedi/ RET`).

   Then run `M-! env/bin/python -c 'import numpy' RET`.  If this does not give you an error, then it should be possible to import numpy and scipy.

I hope at least one of them gives you an error, otherwise I need to think about another possibility.

Comment: I only manage to do this after starting jedi since jedi:server-command is void before that, so is jedi:server-script. I tried putting it in a python-mode hook so that it would only be run after jedi:setup, but keep getting void variable errors.

I dont think I mixed up any installation methods - I followed the instructions for installation with el-get precisely.

Comment: Clrification: I tried first to force the inclusion of the numpy path as described. That did not change anything, still no completion.

Comment: Just call `(require 'jedi)` before using `jedi:server-script`.  You can call it in python-mode-hook if you like.

Comment: I tried all of these options with the following results:
**1. returns error message:** mkdir -p elpa EL4T_EMACS=emacs EMACS=tools/el4t/emacs.sh carton install 2> elpa/install.log make: *** [elpa] Error 127 **the elpa/install.log reads:** /bin/sh: 1: carton: not found   **2. works fine** **3. does not find numpy**

Comment: OK, so I guess `VIRTUALENV_SYSTEM_SITE_PACKAGES=true make clean requirements` should fix your problem.  If it works for you, I will make this default.

Comment: I think that is a good idea. It turns out, on my system that is not enough though, since a combination of apt-get and pip for installing python packages have dispersed my python libraries all over the place..(/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7, dist- and site packages in both /usr/lib/python2.7 and /usr/local/lib/python2.7 etc). I found a solution by activating jedi's virtualenv and using the virtualenvwrapper command add2virtualenv to add all the paths I needed to jedi's virtualenv. I now have completion working for all libraries on the paths that I added to the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

I can get completion such case. Like following

[image]

You may use old requirement modules(jedi, epc, argparse).
You should update them and try again.

Comment: Even though epc and jedi where automatically installed by el-get when I installed emacs-jedi, I did a git pull in those folders just to be sure that I had the latest version. I also did sudo pip install argparse --upgrade which told me I already have the latest version of argparse. So the dependencies seem up to date, but I still do not get completion for numpy or scpipy.

Comment: Hmm, I use epc 0.0.3 and jedi 0.5b5. Please check your epc, jedi version.